# SQL help to make a particular select statement for a table

Tags: sql, sqlite, select

```
CREATE TABLE person (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  first_name TEXT,
  last_name TEXT,
  age INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO person VALUES (0, 'Pat', 'Johnson', 25);
INSERT INTO person VALUES (1, 'John', 'Wells', 28);
```

So I have a table called person and I am trying to query all people younger than `Pat Johnson`, but I do not want to query it by hard coding.

```
SELECT first_name, last_name FROM person WHERE age < 25;
```

^^^ this is an example of what I do not want to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a subquery

```
SELECT first_name, last_name FROM person 
WHERE age<(select age from person where first_name='Pat' and last_name='Johnson')
```

Answer (score 0):

We can try an anti-join approach:

```
SELECT t1.first_name, t1.last_name
FROM yourTable t1
LEFT JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t1.age > t2.age AND
       t2.first_name = 'Pat' AND
       t2.last_name = 'Johnson'
WHERE
    t2.first_name IS NULL;
```